# c++ use async when class destruct it locking,use thread no problem

Tags: c++, asynchronous, dll, future

```
//in dll file
#include <future>
class a
{
public:
    a() 
    {
        //:m_thread=std::thread([this]{});
        m_f = std::async(std::launch::async,[this]{});              
    }       
    ~a() 
    {                                   
        m_f.get();          //most time there m_f lock,sometime not
        //m_thread.join();  //  if use thread no problem
    }
private:
    std::future<void> m_f;  
    //std::thread m_thread;             
};

//out to dll
void aa()
{
    static a aa;
}

//in test file
#include "a.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"a.lib")
int main()
{
    aa();
}
```

if class a is in test file,not in dll file,no problem,use thread no problem,
while the class is in dll file,and the out function use static ,most time it lock,sometime it pass.what's the problem?

Comment: You might want to rephrase that so that it contains a [mcve]. Also, when it locks up, where exactly does it lock up? Attach it to a debugger and stop it to inspect the state of threads and to get a backtrace.